# AngularJS - Prevent radio button from updating model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have tree radiobuttons bound to the same object.

If the user clicks a radio button it immediately changes the model which i try to prevent.

I could store the old value and reassign it after the change but i was wondering if there is a better solution, something like preventDefault..

Background: the click should trigger an server update and the object should only get changed from a server response.

HTML

```
<label ng-click="changeval($event, 0)"><input type="radio" ng-model="radioval" ng-value="0">val0</label>


<label ng-click="changeval($event, 1)"><input type="radio" ng-model="radioval" ng-value="1">val1</label>

<label ng-click="changeval($event, 2)"><input type="radio" ng-model="radioval" ng-value="2">val2</label>
</form>
```

Script

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.radioval = 0;

    $scope.changeval = function(event, timeMode) {

        event.preventDefault();

        // send update to server
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Xsk5X/1055/

It works with a click on the labels but not with a click directly on the radio-circle

Comment: what you are describing isn't how angular is designed to operate.  One of the core features of angular is it's two way binding.

Comment: is the server going to update this `radioval` property to something other than what the button values are? if so, then don't use `ng-model`; if not, then it's not clear why the server has to be in control.

Comment: Server has to be in control to ensure that the database values are the same as shown in the view. All objects get updated by the server which works just fine with the feature of angulars two way binding.

Comment: store old value and revert in promise rejection